# SQL - Running Total (cumulative count of closed tasks) by month

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I am trying to show cumulative count of all closed tasks for year 2019 grouped by project. 
I have made I view and it works partly. But what I want to achieve is when I don't have any closed tasks in year 2019 , but I have them in previous years I want to add number of those tasks to value of Jannuary 2019.

I made i view that counts all tasks cumulative:

```
SELECT 
    *, 
    SUM(a.cnt)  OVER (PARTITION BY Project ORDER BY Jahr,Monat,Project RANGE UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) as cum_cnt_of_tasks
FROM 
    (
    SELECT count(distinct [StoryID])as cnt,datepart(month,[Story_Resolutiondate]) as Monat, datepart(year,[Story_Resolutiondate]) as Jahr,v.ProjectID as  Project
    FROM [Story]s 
    join [Epic]e on s.EpicID=e.EpicID
    join [Project]v on e.ProjectID=v.ProjectID
    group by datepart(month,[Story_Resolutiondate]) ,datepart(year,[Story_Resolutiondate]),v.ProjectID

  ) AS a
```

This is a result:

```
Monat   Jahr       Project         cum_cnt_of_tasks
  6     2017        259052               1
  7     2017        259052               2
  8     2017        259052               3
  9     2017        259052               4
  1     2019        255403               4 
  2     2019        255405               2
```

But I want to turn this into :

```
Monat   Jahr       Project         cum_cnt_of_tasks
  1     2019        259052               4
  1     2019        255403               4 
  2     2019        255405               2
```

So I should take last cumulative value for project 259052 from previous years and map it into value for January 2019:

So last cumulative count for Project 259052 was in september(Monat =9) 2017 . I want to map this value to January 2019.

```
Monat   Jahr       Project         cum_cnt_of_tasks
  6     2017        259052               1
  7     2017        259052               2
  8     2017        259052               3
 *9     2017        259052               4*

                INTO

Monat   Jahr       Project         cum_cnt_of_tasks
 *1     2019        259052               4*
```

@Gordon Linoff
It works if I dont have data after january 2019 but if I do have it then I get from this set:

```
   M      J    Project  cnt
    7   2018    17323   34
    8   2018    17323   36
    9   2018    17323   37
    10  2018    17323   40
    11  2018    17323   41
    12  2018    17323   43
    1   2019    17323   44
    2   2019    17323   47
```

this set:

```
m     j    Project     cnt
2   2019    17323   47
```

But I actually need :

```
m      j    Project  cnt
1   2019    17323     44 
2   2019    17323     47
```

So if January 2019 is already there in dataset than I lose it with your query

Comment: I don't understand the example data. Why did the project 259052 suddenly move to 2019, and why is the count for 2019 4? Is there a typo in it?

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MS SQL Server?

Comment: "Are you using MySQL or MS SQL Server?" he is using SQL Server (MSSQL) pretty sure about that because iám seeing brackets in the SQL code @jarlh

Comment: This is clearly SQL Server, MySQL uses backticks `\`` for quote identifiers, and pretty sure that the `RANGE UNBOUNDED PRECEDING` syntax is T-SQL specific. But, Aleksa, you should really know what  RDBMS you are using. Although they all use SQL, that are all (very different) "flavours" of it.

Comment: "Although they all use SQL, that are all (very different) "flavours" of it." @Larnu i call it SQL dialects.

Comment: @GolezTrol No it is not a typo. Second table is what I want to achieve. I want  to show cumulative count of tasks for project 259052 as a value in january 2019

Comment: @jarlh MSSQL Server

Comment: So, to reword it, you want to roll-over all projects to the current year. You want to count the tasks per project, and list them in the month of the last task, but for all projects that didn't have any activity in 2019, you want to list them in January 2019 instead of the actual month of their last task. Is that right?

Comment: @GolezTrol Exactly!

Answer (score 1):

Use `GROUP BY` and `SUM()`:

```
SELECT
  q.Monat
, q.Jahr
, q.Project
, SUM(q.cum_cnt_of_tasks) SumCnt_of_tasks
FROM
(
SELECT 
    *, 
    SUM(a.cnt)  OVER (PARTITION BY Project ORDER BY Jahr,Monat,Project RANGE 
        UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) as cum_cnt_of_tasks
FROM 
    (
    SELECT 
    count(distinct [StoryID])as cnt
    , datepart(month,[Story_Resolutiondate]) as Monat
    , datepart(year,[Story_Resolutiondate]) as Jahr
    ,v.ProjectID as  Project
    FROM [Story]s 
    join [Epic]e on s.EpicID=e.EpicID
    join [Project]v on e.ProjectID=v.ProjectID
    group by  datepart(month,[Story_Resolutiondate]) 
             ,datepart(year,[Story_Resolutiondate])
             ,v.ProjectID    
  ) AS a 
)q
GROUP BY   q.Monat
         , q.Jahr
         , q.Project
         , q.cum_cnt_of_tasks
```

**UPDATE:**

Try to use the following query:

```
SELECT 
  CASE 
    WHEN t.Jahr = 2017 THEN 1
    ELSE MAX(t.Monat)
  END AS Monat     
, CASE 
    WHEN t.Jahr = 2017 THEN 2019
    ELSE t.Jahr
  END AS Jahr
, t.Project
, COUNT(t.cum_cnt_of_tasks) Cnt
FROM @Table t
GROUP BY 
  t.Jahr
, t.Project
```

An example data:

```
DECLARE @Table TABLE
(
    Monat  INT,
    Jahr INT,
    Project INT,
    cum_cnt_of_tasks INT
)

INSERT INTO @Table
(
    Monat,
    Jahr,
    Project,
    cum_cnt_of_tasks
)
VALUES
  (   6,     2017,        259052,               1)
, (   7,     2017,        259052,               2)
, (   8,     2017,        259052,               3)
, (   9,     2017,        259052,               4)
, (   1,     2019,        255403,               4) 
, (   2,     2019,        255405,               2)
```

An OUTPUT:

```
Monat   Jahr    Project   Cnt
1       2019    255403     1
2       2019    255405     1
1       2019    259052     4
```

Comment: count(distinct [StoryID]) Cannot  be used in an expression used for the group by list of a GROUP BY clause . And second thing is that you are making a sum of ProjectIDs , i need count

Comment: Let me explain one more time. Maybe the explanation is unclear. My view above works. It does count all tasks cumulative. What I want to achieve is to transform this view in order to get second table from example above.

Comment: I have changed question. Maybe is now better explained.

Comment: @AleksaStanojlovic please, see my updated section of answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do this with a single aggregation:

```
select (case when max(Story_Resolutiondate) < '2019-01-01' then 1 else month(max(Story_Resolutiondate))
        end) as monat,
       (case when max(Story_Resolutiondate) < '2019-01-01' then 2019 else year(max(Story_Resolutiondate))
        end) as jarh,
       v.projectId,
       count(distinct StoryId)
from [Story] s join
     [Epic] e 
     on s.EpicID = e.EpicID join
     [Project] v 
     on e.ProjectID = v.ProjectID
group by v.ProjectId;
```

I'm not 100% the count is exactly what you want.  Your data suggests that you want a count of *months*, but your query has different logic.  Either is quite doable.

EDIT:

I think `union all` may do what you want:

```
select 1 as monat, 2019 as jarh, v.projectId, count(distinct StoryId)
from [Story] s join
     [Epic] e 
     on s.EpicID = e.EpicID join
     [Project] v 
     on e.ProjectID = v.ProjectID
group by v.ProjectId
having max(Story_Resolutiondate) < '2019-01-01'
union all
select month(Story_Resolutiondate) as monat, 
       year(Story_Resolutiondate) as jahr,
       v.projectId, count(distinct StoryId)
from [Story] s join
     [Epic] e 
     on s.EpicID = e.EpicID join
     [Project] v 
     on e.ProjectID = v.ProjectID
where Story_Resolutiondate >= '2019-01-01'
group by v.ProjectId, year(Story_Resolutiondate), month(Story_Resolutiondate)
```

Comment: I have added results after your query to question above ,because you can see it better